# Obj-C to Swift3 for class returning method

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

So I have this method in Obj-C superclass:

```
+ (Class<Executor>)executorClass
```

I need to override it in my Swift3 child class. What I tried:

```
override class func executorClass() -> AnyClass // not match

override class func executorClass() -> Executor.Type // not match

override class func executorClass() -> AnyObject.Type // not match

override class func executorClass() -> Any.Type // obviously not match
```

Before in Swift2 the following code worked:

```
override class func executorClass() -> AnyObject.Type
```

Comment: If `AnyObject.Type` worked in Swift2, then `AnyClass` should be a match for Swift3. Here is the [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyclass).

Comment: @nayem in fact it doesn't work. I will try to create a new project with 2 classes only to check if it is because of my project environment, some side effects or whatever.

Comment: Well `Class` doesn't have any lightweight generic placeholders, so `Class<Executor>` isn't legal. Assuming `executorClass` just returns a `Class`, `override class func executorClass() -> AnyClass` should work fine.

Comment: @Hamish as I marked in question, `-> AnyClass` breaks compilation with `Method does not override any method from its superclass`. I created sample project with only 2 classes, and this behaviour can be easily reproduced. By the way, I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 if it is relevant.

Comment: @Hamish It seems that problem was in Obj-C as you said. `Class<Executor>` isn't legal but still compilable. Removing `<Executor` solves the problem

Comment: @TienNguyen Actually strictly speaking I was mistaken in saying that it wasn't legal – as Sulthan points out below, it *is* legal if `Executor` is a protocol (TIL), but illegal if it is a class (which I assume is the case here, otherwise a return type of `Executor.Type` should've worked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Harnish

<del>The `Class<Executor>` in Obj-C method isn't legal, but still compilable.</del> Removing `<Executor>` solves compilation. aka:

```
// Obj-C
+ (Class)executorClass

// Swift
override class func executorClass() -> AnyClass  // good
```

**Edit:** credit to @Sulthan

```
+ (Class<Executor>)executorClass
```

Above code is fully legal if `Executor` was protocol. However in my case it was another class. So, I guessing, this was the root of the problem.

Comment: Obj-C `< ... >` mixes syntax for protocols and for generics and it can be a bit confusing. I would assume `Executor` to be a protocol.